# Convert hash with backslash to json in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am using the following Rails and Ruby versions for my application.

Rails - 6.0.3

Ruby - 2.7.0p0

```
input = "{\"type\"=>\"service_account\", \"project_id\"=>\"test\"}"

JSON.parse(input)

Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):15
JSON::ParserError (783: unexpected token at '{"type"=>"manager", "name"=>"John"}')
```

I want to convert above input to json. Result should be passed to credentials in [Google Big Query](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/Google/Cloud/Bigquery/Credentials.html)

Comment: This does not look like JSON at all, it looks like Ruby.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Input is from Postgres DB in Rails app. I want to pass to credentials in Google BigQuery as json.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** As correctly pointed out by Siim Liiser it could break for a case if values had `=>` in them

You could try using:

```
JSON.load( input.gsub(/(?<=\")=>/, ":") )
```

this would give you output something like this for above input:

```
{"type"=>"service_account", "project_id"=>"test"}
```

for something like Siim Liiser suggested:

```
input = "{\"type\"=> \"service_account\", \"project_id\"=> \"test\", \"typer\"=>\"service=>account\" }"
#=> {"type"=>"service_account", "project_id"=>"test", "typer"=>"service=>account"}
```

Good thing just to be extra sure.

Comment: It breaks if the input contains => in some other places. Like "name" which looks like user input

Comment: Agreed. but this was for the case listed above. Please tell me your case, I'll find a solution for it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching the problem slightly wrong. The input you have is not valid JSON. It does however look like a ruby hash that has incorrectly been stored in the database.

I suggest investigating how it is stored. Either convert the hash to JSON before storing it so it can then be reliably parsed after retrieving it, or store it in a column that is designed to hold JSON. In postgres that would be json or jsonb.

If that does not apply to you, we can still try converting your given input.

Safely converting it to valid json is difficult without more background information. If you know it was always a ruby hash with string values before being converted to a string, then you could `eval()` it to get the hash back. If you know that the string will never contain `=>` in any of the keys or values, then you can `gsub` them to `:` and parse as JSON.

Comment: Input column type is String. I am passing as input as JSON.parse('{\"type\"=>\"service_account\", \"project_id\"=>\"test\"}') to store in postgres database. My other values to the column are String. So column type is String. What is the best way to fetch from db and pass it as json to some other method.

Comment: Do not, *ever* use `eval`. Please. Do yourself, and most importantly all your users, whose data *will* be stolen, a favor.

Comment: @JörgWMittag How can I achieve the required output without using eval? Any suggestions

Comment: It makes zero sense to pass around a Ruby `Hash` as a `String` with Ruby source code. Either pass the Ruby `Hash` around as, you know, a Ruby `Hash`, or serialize it to a `String` using some well-known serialization format such as JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You can simple gsub => to : before JSON parse.

Comment: It breaks if the input contains => in some other places. Like "name" which looks like user input